# Does Facebook Audience network support app-ads.txt?

Tags: facebook-audience-network

The [policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/policy) says

> Publishers that maintain an ads.txt or app-ads.txt file must include
>   Audience Network listed appropriately and accurately.

What line needs to be included in the `app-ads.txt` file?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
facebook.com, Business ID, RESELLER, c3e20eee3f780d68
```

according to Facebook Audience Network documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/authorized-sellers